# study of the properties of a ring with several quadratic elements

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

here is my question.
I am currently studying the case of quadratic number rings and I find quite strange that the classification of $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}]$ appears in so many books whereas I can't find any study concerning $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d},\sqrt{d'}]$. For instance, what about $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{3},\sqrt{11}]$? It seems to me that it is noetherian, but I have no idea whether it is integrally closed or how to describe the ideals, or any other interesting property I could investigate.
Thanks for any comment!

Answer (score 1):

That is because these tend to be harder to deal with.
In any case, $\Bbb Z[\sqrt3,\sqrt{11}]$ is not integrally closed,
as $\alpha=\frac12(\sqrt3+\sqrt{11})$ is an algebraic integer. Indeed
$\alpha^2=\frac12(7+\sqrt{33})$ so that $\alpha^4-7\alpha^2+4=0$.

But $\Bbb Z[\sqrt3,\sqrt{11}]$ is Noetherian, as it's a homomorphic
image of the Noetherian domain $\Bbb Z[X,Y]$ (Hilbert Basis Theorem).

Comment: Thanks! Anyway I don't understand why many books don't warn the reader that some rings are "hard" to study and just tell what is currently known, or reachable for the student.